# Font Awesome How To

Tags: html, fonts

In the header of my website I have my phone number in a line a of code

```
<b><h2><FONT size="4" COLOR="#FFfff"> CALL US TODAY 512-323-9006</FONT></h2></b>
```

What I am trying to do is add the font awesome phone icon  `<i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i>`

When I add this The phone icon appears above the call us line of text.

My question: how do I add the icon inline just before the ''call us'' text?

thank you in advance

Comment: Where did you put that line of code? Above the h2? Why not put it in the h2 tag?

Comment: Are you trying to add an image by setting the `background-image` on an `<i>` tag?  That's...a unique way of doing it.

Comment: @paul.abbott.wa.us FontAwesome uses CSS classes to render icons. It's actually an icon font, not images. Although using `background` properties to show images is actually surprisingly versatile (with related background properties, it's much more flexible than `<img src='' />`)

Answer (score 1):

The `<h2>` tag is a [block level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), which means it will take up the full width and not allow anything to be positioned next to it. You can overwrite this behavior in CSS by using `inline-block`:

```
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

`inline-block` is really nice because it allows the element to be positioned 'inline', which means elements only take up as much width as their content and they can be positioned next to other elements. At the same time, you are able to set block-level properties such as `margin` and `padding`, which don't take effect on `inline` elements.

Examples of `inline-block`: http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/